# Can new users to a SE 1.0 site be allowed to post images?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, images

Many months ago, I started the Stack Exchange 1.0 site `www.panoverflow.com` as a kind of companion site to my main startup, `www.360cities.net`, which is a commmunity website where photographers publish their — technically perfect — 360 panoramic photos. The purpose of panoverflow is to help people who want to create spherical panoramas; this is not an easy thing to do, even for experienced photographers!

Long story short, my original idea for the site was that panoramic photographers who didn't yet have the skills to make technically correct 360 panoramas would be able to post their image to panoverflow and get technical critiques. Posting a link to the panorama on another site really doesn't cut it.

Is it possible for new users of a Stack Exchange 1.0 site to post images? For my situation, this is required — if it's not possible, I'll have to (sigh) use a normal forum, or (no!!!!) build something from scratch.

Comment: This ability has been added to SE 2.0 as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 4):

Since the release of StackExchange 2.0, StackExchange 1.0 sites only get bugfixes, not new features.

Comment: so we can get them to darn upgrade for the good of their communities. :D

Answer (score 2):

Development of Stack Exchange 1.0 ceased many months ago. At that time, image uploads were not possible, so SE 1.0 sites will never receive this feature.

> Long story short, my original idea for the site was that panoramic photographers who didn't yet have the skills to make technically correct 360 panoramas would be able to post their image to panoverflow and get technical critiques

In addition, the Stack Exchange Q&A model is not really designed for this, as threaded discussion, which is what is best suited for what you want, is not possible on SE. I would suggest you use a traditional forum solution like [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com) or [Invision Power Board](http://www.invisionpower.com/products/board/).

Comment: aren't we having a threaded discussion right now? :)

my attraction to using stackexchange is the very well though-out karma system, which is a great motivator for users. far more so than normal forums, i feel.

Comment: @user Not really. We're more of answers with extremely poor support in the form of comments. In a real threaded discussion forum, these responsive comments could have things like images, and the ability to be found via search.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a tag on the existing

http://photo.stackexchange.com

site .. which *is* a SE 2.0 site?

Comment: "
StackExchange couldn't find photos.stackexchange.com.

The StackExchange site photos.stackexchange.com doesn't exist yet.

Would you like to create it?
"

Comment: good point -- we're now redirecting the pluralization

Comment: still an error http://photos.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/